# Unable to get light theme on React Tailwind Datepicker. Any solutions?

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, tailwind-css

How to change color theme of React Tailwind Datepicker

```
<Datepicker
  asSingle={true}
  containerClassName="relative mt-8 bg-gray-100"
  displayFormat={"DD/MM/YYYY"}
  // maxDate={new Date()}
  minDate={new Date()}
  primaryColor={"green"}
  // startFrom={minDate()}
  useRange={false}
  value={value}
  onChange={handleValueChange}
/>;
```

Npm package:
`npm i react-tailwindcss-datepicker`

I want to get the light theme, but unable to get the CSS through console too.
Link to the page: https://react-tailwindcss-datepicker.vercel.app/theming-options
There is no code snippet for changing the default dark theme to light.

Comment: the docs shows that the light theme is the default theme
https://react-tailwindcss-datepicker.vercel.app/theming-options#light-mode

Answer (score 5):

Was facing same issue, didn't find anything on docs. If you are using only light theme in you app do this workaround.
GO TO tailwind.config.js and put this `darkMode: ""`

like this

```
export default {
  darkMode: '',
  ...restOptions
}
```

Update: Some info from offical doc:
[Toggling dark mode manually](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/dark-mode)

Comment: works like charm...hope it does not disturb other styles

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to get the light theme on the calendar by setting this in my Tailwind config:

```
const config: Config = {
  darkMode: ['class'],
  ...
}
```

and here is my JSX

```
  <Datepicker
    startFrom={new Date()}
    useRange={false}
    asSingle={true}
    value={selectedDate || null}
    onChange={handleValueChange}
    showFooter={true}
    placeholder="Select a date"
    inputClassName={inputClassName}
  />
```

I am using typescript so the top answer didn't work to a type mismatch.